# Eigenvalue replacing matrices in matrix equation?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Found this confusing pieces of equations in Liquid Crystal, from *Fundamentals of Liquid Crystal Devices(2006)*, Wiley,  Deng-ke Yang, Shin-Tson Wu.

if A is an 2X2 matrix, from Cayley-Hamilton Theory A can be expanded as

$$A^N = \lambda_1 I + \lambda_2 A$$

this part is quite easy, but i can't understand the following part. According to the book, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ can be found from the equations
$$ q_1^N = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2Aq_1$$
$$ q_2^N = \lambda_2 + \lambda_2Aq_2$$

where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are the eigenvalues of matrix A.

How is this trivial? Can you prove or explain why it make sense? Even a small lead or hint would be great help!

P.S: for $\lambda_2Aq_1,_2$, i think A might be typing error. If that is the case, can you replace matrix with its eigenvalue for all equations involving matrices? or is this just a special case?

P.S2: Sorry for the poor sentences :< english is not my first language.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in $q_1^N = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2Aq_1$. It should be $q_1^N = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2q_1$. Here you are using the fact that $A\mathbf{v}=q_1\mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the eigen vector corresponding to the eigen value $q_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from 
$$A^N = \lambda_1 I + \lambda_2 A$$
Suppose $\mathbf{v}$ is the eigen vector corresponding to the eigenvalue $q_1$, then
$$A\mathbf{v}=q_1\mathbf{v}.$$
From the first equation it follows:
$$A^N \mathbf{v} = \lambda_1 I\mathbf{v} + \lambda_2 A\mathbf{v}.$$
Using the second equation, we get
$$(q_1^N - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2q_1) \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}.$$
But $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$ (since it is an eigen vector). Thus
$$q_1^N - \lambda_1 - \lambda_2q_1=0.$$
Likewise you get the second equation. Now your unknowns are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ and you have two equations so use Gaussian elimination.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & q_1 & q_1^N\\
1 & q_2 & q_2^N\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$